# Do I need to implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError in iOS7+ app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iad, adbannerview

I'm implementing a new app for iOS7+. The integration with iAd banners seems easy with canDisplayBannerAds in the views i want to display a banner. However i'm getting this errors in Xcode log:

```
ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0xc07bcc0 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}
```

Since in iOS7 iAd framework you only need to set canDisplayBannerAds = YES, is it necessary to continue doing `Banner.delegate = self` or implementing didFailToReceiveAdWithError?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it needs to implement if you want some action or UI change when adview failed to receive ad.

Answer (score 1):

`bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` is optional in `ADBannerViewDelegate` protocol (located in ADBannerView.h).

So all you need to do is set the Banner delegate and it should work well.
Concerning `canDisplayBannerAds` property, the [Apple Documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/canDisplayBannerAds) states that it is:

> A boolean value that indicates whether the view controller is
>   configured to display banner ads.

So I don't think canDisplayBannerAds has anything to do with delegation.
You should check that page from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW3).

Comment: So to get that clear. I only need `@interface SViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>` in *.h and `[self canDisplayBannerAds]` in *.m and that's it? because my app is not listed in the iAd network. Contract is made. And iAd is added to my apps.

Comment: for the iAd network you might want to check on itunes connect or something. But in any case you have to set the delegate of your bannerView

Comment: I have done that and that was sort of logical in the end. But I can ignore the delegate methods, right?

Comment: bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: is optional in ADBannerViewDelegate. So yes you can ignore it. It won't crash it it's not implemented